# Using xpathSApply in R. Empty list is the output instead of values

Tags: r

I have a problem in web scraping in R. I am doing the following example but not getting the values instead getting list() which has zero elements

```
library(XML)

url<-"http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HI-I6C0AAAAJ"

parsedhtml<-htmlTreeParse(url,useInternalNodes=T)

xpathSApply(parsedhtml,"//td[@id='col-citedby']",xmlValue)
```

I am getting `list()` after I compute the following code

Comment: Using `RCurl` and `getURL()` then using `grepl()` to test if that attribute exists in there returns false.  Are you confident it's in there?  I may have done it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your xpath is most likely incorrect. If you just want a list of citations try:

```
library(XML)
url<-"http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HI-I6C0AAAAJ"
parsedhtml<-htmlParse(url)
parsedhtml["//a[@class='gsc_a_ac']", fun = xmlValue]
```

Comment: I get error `parsedhtml<-htmlParse(url)#Error: failed to load HTTP resource`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    library(httr)
    url<-"http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HI-I6C0AAAAJ"
    page<-GET(url)
parsedhtml<-htmlParse(page,useInternalNodes=T)
xpathSApply(parsedhtml,"//td[@id='col-citedby']",xmlValue)
```